# Are the C1 and C3 carbons of cis 1-bromo-3-chloro-cyclobutane chiral?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, chirality

I have tried to approach this from 2 directions:

The ‘official’ method my textbook gives, which gives the correct answer - They are achiral

It consists of going ‘priority-wise’ from the two carbons to see if they are unsymmetrical. Which, both carbons connected to C1 (and C3 in the other case) ultimately meeting the same atom C3 (and C1 in the other case), gives no as an answer.

I tried to approach this by interchanging the positions of H and Br on C1 and seeing if I could superimpose this and the original structure, which I should be able to because C1 is symmetrical.

Are they superimposable? Am I doing the superimposing wrong? I have been trying to superimpose them in my mind for quite some time and have been unsuccessful (I’ll get the ‘balls and sticks’ kit after the lockdown ends to get a more intuitive understanding).

Or are they not superimposable and I’m missing something?

Edit: Adding a picture of the compound (It is meant to be in cis form) :
[image: Compound]

Comment: C1 and C3 are stereogenic but achirotopic. A change of stereochemistry at either carbon creates cis/trans isomers (stereogenic) but the cis/trans isomers will always be achiral.

Comment: A drawing(s) on some sort would go along way for people to better interpret the question.

Comment: @user55119 So the 2 structures can be superimposed?

Comment: I know you’re waiting to get a kit, but perhaps look into a 3D drawing program like Avogadro. Sorry for not mentioning this earlier.

Comment: Gist - There is a mirror plane through the Br, Cl, and the two carbons to which the halogens are attached.

Comment: Imagine the cis and trans isomers as ghosts. Slide one into the other. Do all atoms match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are achiral. If you take the mirror image (first picture) and rotate 180 degrees (second picture), you can overlay them. Images made with [Avogadro](https://avogadro.cc/)

[image: Mirror]

[image]